# How to get ItemTemplate Property

Tags: asp.net, datagridview

I want to get value of generated HTML  of an ItemTemplate in gridView

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mark">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <input type="text" value="<%# Eval("mark") %>" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

I try this :

```
GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Controls[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use asp.net server control to get the value in back end.
**ASP.NET**

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="نمره">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbMark" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("mark") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

**C#**

```
String mark = (GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
```

Comment: this error occurred : An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_d320vpud.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this template

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="نمره">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <input type="text" runat="server" Id="MyInput" value="<%# Eval("mark") %>" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>



string Mark = ctype(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].findeControl("MyInput"), htmlinput).value
```

Comment: string Mark = ctype(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].FindControl("mark"),HtmlInput).Value; this code has syntax error!